# Select the next day occurance from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

This is my db structure of the table game days. Every game ends at 8:00 pm . Here all the game id is same.So now i want to query by the game id like this way that if today is monday and it is before 8:00 pm so it will fetch only the game_days with value of day='Monday'.Once 8:00pm is over then it will show the row with the value of day='Wednesday' until wednesday 8:00pm and after 8:00 pm it will show the row with the value of day='Friday' until Friday 8:00pm and then again after Friday 8:00pm it will show Monday...

So what will be the query for this ?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: i have not tried anything..because i have not idea regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (updated based on comments, replace table_name with appropriate table name is your db):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name`
WHERE day = (
    SELECT t3.day FROM `table_name` as t3
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT HOUR(NOW()), 
        CASE
            WHEN HOUR(NOW()) <= 19 THEN DAYNAME(NOW() + INTERVAL t.p DAY)
            ELSE DAYNAME(NOW() + INTERVAL (t.p + 1) DAY)
        END AS day, 
        CASE
            WHEN HOUR(NOW()) <= 19 THEN  t.p
            ELSE t.p + 1
        END as p
        FROM (
            SELECT 0 as p
            UNION SELECT 1 as p 
            UNION SELECT 2 as p
            UNION SELECT 3 as p
            UNION SELECT 4 as p
            UNION SELECT 5 as p
            UNION SELECT 6 as p
        ) t
   ) t2 on t3.day = t2.day
   ORDER BY t2.p ASC LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: i tried this  ...as now it is over 8:00pm so it should show the row monday ..but it is showing the column with friday @Limexs

Comment: Should it jump to Monday from Friday when day is Friday and time is > 8PM?

Comment: Currently it should be looking for record with day = 'Saturday'

Comment: yes ..if there is no record for saturday then it should  fetch the data for monday ...

Comment: please try updated sql, however doing all in your program instead of SQL would be better if number for records in your table are too large

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the date offset by 4 hours.  One method is:

```
where date(updated_at + interval 4 hour) = curdate()
```

I am guessing that `updated_at` is the column you want to reference, but it can be any date/time column.

I prefer to express this as:

```
where updated_at >= curdate() - interval 4 hour and
      updated_at < curdate() + interval 1 day - interval 4 hour
```

This version can make use of an index on the date/time column.